# SSAS VM on Azure Authentication

Tags: azure, ssas, windows-authentication, iaas

I have a customer who intends to host SSAS VM in Azure. How will they best be able to authenticate against it without connecting to their own corporate AD?

Can one setup AD for them in the Cloud only for this Authentication?. SSAS requires Windows Authentication. Client doesn't want to setup any on Prem configurations due to security reasons.

Comment: What client tool are you going to use? Do they do Office 365 or Power BI or anything requiring Azure Active Directory yet?

Comment: SSAS Multidimensional or Tabular?

Comment: They intend to access the Tabular models via on of a few tools (PBI, Excel, Tableau) remotely over the internet.

Comment: can you answer the other two questions?

Comment: Is Azure Analysis Services (PaaS rather than VM) an option? https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/analysis-services/

Comment: They currently don't use o365 or Power BI.

Comment: No, SSAS PaaS is not an option due to cost.